# Why do some native Japanese speakers put a comma after a particle?

Tags: punctuation

Example:

> あなたは、きっと日本の抹茶ティーは嫌いだね

This is how I'm seeing the sentence:

> You'll, certainly hate Matcha tea in Japan.

Or maybe I'm translating the sentence in the wrong way? Anyhow, could be the reason of putting that comma there?

Comment: Commas aren't used the same way in Japanese as they are in English.